# How to do SSR with stencil.js in a project with Nuxt.js (SSR as well)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, stenciljs

I want to use a `stencil` library in my `nuxt` project.

I was able to get it working, but while the `vue` components are being rendered in the server side, I only could make the `stencil`'s component to render in the client side.

I think the biggest problem is that the `defineCustomElement` needs the `window` as a parameter.

I know that `stencil.js` has that "prerender" which is basically SSR in my understanding, I wanted to use it as well as `Nuxt.js` SSR.

So my question is : how to configure a `nuxt` project to support server side rendering for `stencil.js`?

Comment: you cant. Support of SSR is something that should be done at library level. So stencil.js either support ssr or dont support. If it relies on window - it dont support ssr.

Comment: see https://github.com/jagreehal/stencil-ssr-example

Answer (score 2):

Update: I'm currently developing a Nuxt module to integrate with stencil.js based libraries.

https://github.com/Gomah/nuxt-stencil

What it does:

- It creates two hooks for SSR based applications (universal or build-time) using the `render:route` & `generate:page`, it will render the stencil components before sending back the request to the browser.
- It injects a plugin for CSR to define the custom elements from your stencil library, as described [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/vue).

*⚠️ Note: Vue’s throwing few errors when hydrating on CSR, it's probably due to the comments that the renderer inject when rendering stencil components*

---

---

*Outdated comment, before Stencil V1:*

It looks like Stencil v1 might resolve SSR, according to this [comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1449#issuecomment-482122185):

> Stencil One will use the dist-hydrate-script output target to generate
>   a node script that can be used to hydrate your scripts. Then the
>   generated dist/hydrate/index.js script is something you can reuse in
>   numerous locations (Angular Universal, Express Middleware, custom
>   prerendering, etc).
>
> If you're prerendering, you'll be able to just add the --prerender
>   flag to your stencil build, and it'll handle all of this for you.
>   We're still actively working on this and hope to ship it soon. Thanks

Github related issues:

https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1036

https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1449

Answer (score 0):

oh yeah, as Aldarund, said, you can't, I took a better look at the [prerendering page](https://stenciljs.com/docs/prerendering) and it's said there that the prerender happens on build time, so this will not be possible :/ too bad

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you have a workaround

1. You must publish you webcomponent in unpkg or any other public (or private) CDN
2. In your nuxt.config.js file, add script in your section script. This script must be ref to your public lib (https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript)

For further information about how to add an external resource to your nuxt project, please read: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/ -> How to use external resources

Cheers

Comment: sorry, but, does this method works with server side rendering? is it delivered to the client in a pre rendered way?

Answer (score 0):

For the people using nuxt 3. I have found a solution to use stencil with nuxt 3 ssr. You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73036156/10875110) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72478699/10875110).